# Load UICollectionViewCell from nib without reuse

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a custom UICollectionViewCell with a nib that I would like to load in UICollectionView's cellForItemAt method but without getting/instantiating the cell from the collection view's dequeueReusableCell method.

The issue I'm encountering is that when plainly loading the cell like:

```
let cell = MyCustomCell()
```

It's IB properties aren't loaded, I've tried also calling:

```
cell.awakeFromNib() and/or layoutIfNeeded()
```

with no effect. I can get the views to load from IB using the dequeue method, but as stated, can't use it.

I am properly registering the nib in viewDidLoad of the view controller where the collection view lives:

```
let name = String(describing: MyCustomCell.self)
collectionView.register(
    UINib(
        name: name,
        bundle: nil),
    forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why IBOutlets are not working on your instance of MyCustomCell is because only the class is being instantiated and not the xib/nib.
When you register a cell in a tableView and then dequeue that cell both are getting initialized and there's where the magic happens.

If you really want to load a cell without using dequeue method of the tableview this is what you can do:

1. Create a var of your UITableViewCell custom class, in this case is  MyCustomCell

   ```
   var notReusableCell:CellTableViewCell?
   ```
2. In viewDidLoad the nib and get the view that you want in this case we want the cell so that will be the first view.

   `let nib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CellTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)
   notReusableCell = nib?.first as! CellTableViewCell?`
3. Now in your cellForRowAt method pass the cell stored in your var

   `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       guard let cell = notReusableCell else { return CellTableViewCell() }
       return cell
   }`

Please revise what you are trying to do since this kind of practices are not common.

Comment: You're 100% right - instead I just used a few different cells different reuse identifiers and dequeued them as normal, if you want to update your answer to suggest that I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: That's great that you get the right approach! I think my response answers the question of the post, so I'll be really happy if you accept it :)